# Android xmpp buddy status error

Tags: android, xmpp

I am working on a chat application. I need to display the buddy list in a listview with image name of the buddy and status.

I can get the name of the buddy and status always returns unavailable. Snippet code is given below.

```
for (RosterEntry r : entries) {
            {
                presence = roster.getPresence(r.getUser());
                // status = presence.getType().name();
                status = presence.getType().name();

                buddyNameList[i] = r.getName() + "\t" + status;
```

Why is always status return unavailable. Where am i doing wrong. Kindly guide me in this issue. I also need to know how to get the buddy image from xmpp.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you haven't waited long enough for presence to arrive.  It does so asynchronously, and there's no way to tell when you're "done" receiving presence.  You should probably just subscribe to notifications for presence change.